# SQL : Varchar add space to the end of the text

Tags: sql, varchar

When I add element to column (varchar) I get extra space. For example if I have a table `Student` with `name varchar(10)` and I do:

```
INSERT INTO Student (id,name) VALUES (1,'student')
SELECT name FROM Student WHERE id=1
```

I get `student[space][space][space]`.

How can I fix without changing the type to `text`?

Comment: Please show us that the column is VARCHAR, rather than CHAR.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases output results from a query in a fixed tabular format.  To see where a string really begins and ends, you need to concatenate another character.  Here are three ways, depending on the database:

```
select '"'+name+'"'
select '"'||name||'"'
select concat('"', name, '"')
```

You'll probably find that the spaces are an artifact of the query tool.